# What are the ways to styling a Django Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, django-bootstrap3

I was working with Django forms, and to beautify the Django forms I came across widgets, and after learning it got to know that we can customize widgets in two ways:

1. Using widget instance or
2. Using widget class.

Later came across `django-crispy` and `django-bootstrap` that allow same beautification of the forms along with various other advantages over other.

But I was wondering, how many more such library / packages / apps are there, and is there any short of description for each, which might help me and others too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For simple design or not any extra validation in frontend bootstrap or crispy form is okay.
But if you want to take advantages of custom `css` `js` then widget is better option obviously.
I generally do:

- create a form using css, js even if in bootstrap
- Then pass the classes or id of the particular field in widget